# Limit points of the set $A=\lbrace(-1)^{n}(1+\frac{1}{n})^{n-1}\mid n\in\mathbb{N}\rbrace$

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

I have searched for a question similar to this and unfortunately I have not found one.Let $A=\lbrace(-1)^{n}(1+\frac{1}{n})^{n-1}\mid n\in\mathbb{N}\rbrace$ be a subset of Euclidean space $(\mathbb{R},|.|)$. If we denote the set of limit points of $A$ with $A'$, then is it true that $A'=\emptyset$?I must insist that the proof should only contain the concepts regarding limit points and neighborhoods and I am not allowed to use any sequence related concepts. I tried to introduce $0<r_{0}\in\mathbb{R}$ where $N_{r_{0}}(x)\cap A=\emptyset$ for any $x\in\mathbb{R}$ where $r_{0}=\frac{1}{2}(|(-1)^{n}(1+\frac{1}{n})^{n-1}-(-1)^{n-1}(1+\frac{1}{n})^{n-2}|)=\frac{1}{2}(2+\frac{1}{n})(1+\frac{1}{n})^{n-2}\\$ but I cannot proceed any further. Any helps are most appreciated.

Comment: A should have at least two limit points.

Comment: How did you conclude that?

Comment: You're going to need to use the fact that $\lim\left(1+\frac1n\right)^n=e$; is that a "sequence-related concept", being the limit of a sequence???

Comment: How should I use it? By proving that it is a supremum for $A$? Can you please help how I should do it?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it would be useful to make a partition of $A$ according to the parity of $n$ and then consider the supremum/infimum of the resulting sets.

$A=A^+ \cup A^-$, where $A^+=\{e^{(2n-1)\log (1+1/2n)}, n\in \mathbb{N} \} $ and $A^-=\{-e^{2n\log (1+1/(2n+1))}, n\in \mathbb{N} \} $.

It remains to study the limit points of $\{n \log(1+1/n)\}$,which is unique: 1

Comment: Could you please add to your kindness and explain how you concluded that the limit points of $\lbrace nlog(1+\frac{1}{n})\rbrace$ is unique and equal to 1?

Comment: The set $\{ x_n=n \log(1+1/n) \}$ is discrete so neither of the points $x_n$ are accumulation points. Now consider a large $n$ and write $\log(1+1/n)=1/n+0(1/n^2)$, then $x_n=1+O(1/n)$. So for any small enough neighborhood of $1$, there are infinitely many $x_n$'s close to 1.